# nested for loop value of not initialized

Tags: c, for-loop, initialization

I know question sounds dumb, I can't really figure out what is wrong in this code?

```
void sort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; i < size; j++)
        {
            if (arr[min] > arr[j])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i)
        {
            Swap(&arr[i], &arr[min]);
        }
    }    
}
```

The following code should sort the `arr` but it is giving segmentation fault.
I ran this code via debugger and it says the value of `j` at line

```
        for (int j = i; i < size; j++)
```

something like `3234` (not initialized) and program ends. But `j` should be `0`.

[debuger screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIYF4.jpg)

Comment: In `for(int j = i;i<size;j++)` the value of `i` never changes, so it spins forever..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second `for` loop, it should be `j < size`, not `i < size`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems in your `sort` function:

- The test in the inner `for` loop uses `i` instead of `j`. `j` is initialized but the test always succeeds and the loop goes on, letting the code access `arr` beyond its boundaries, causing undefined behavior.
- `min` should initialized to `i` inside the outer loop,
- `j` should be initialized to `i + 1` is the inner loop (minor).

Here is a corrected version:

```
void sort(int *arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[min] > arr[j]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i) {
            Swap(&arr[i], &arr[min]);
        }
    }
}
```